# passing PHP arrays in WebAudio Buffers

Tags: javascript, php, wav, file-get-contents, web-audio-api

For a web application I am working on, I need to get a WAV audio file from a different server into a webAudio buffer based on a URL generated from a PHP script.

To do this, I generate the URL in a PHP script and then use that URL to get the contents of that WAV file as an array like so:

```
$this->audioBuffer = file($this->stationAudioURL);
```

then, in the page with the webAudio script, I try to pass the array from PHP and decode it in the webAudio context here:

```
<?php require_once('getSeismicData.php'); ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var eventOneAudio = <?php echo json_encode($eventOne->audioBuffer); ?>;
var eventTwoAudio = <?php echo json_encode($eventTwo->audioBuffer); ?>;
var eventThreeAudio = <?php echo json_encode($eventThree->audioBuffer); ?>;


var eventOneBuffer = null;
var eventTwoBuffer = null;
var eventThreeBuffer = null;

window.AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
var context = new AudioContext();

context.decodeAudioData(eventOneAudio, function(buffer){eventOneBuffer = buffer});
context.decodeAudioData(eventTwoAudio, function(buffer){eventTwoBuffer = buffer});
context.decodeAudioData(eventThreeAudio, function(buffer){eventThreeBuffer = buffer});
```

What would be the proper way to implement this? More specifically:

1) should I use `file()` or `file_get_contents()` to get the WAV file?

2) should I use `json_encode()` or just `echo` the wav file directly to the javascript?

full source code on git: https://github.com/felakuti4life/Seismokraft